# GWT getAbsoluteLeft/Top returns wrong value in FF

Tags: gwt

when i call the getAbsoluteLeft/Top method i always get 0 in firefox. For the IE i get a value which seems to be correct. Are there known problems using these methods ? My problem is that i want to set the position of an element with the absolute position values of another element. Thanks in advance. Edit: Using GWT 2.0.3

kuku

EDIT Testcase:
1. The host page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="samplegwt/samplegwt.nocache.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function execute() {
    var element = document.getElementById("paragraph");    
    if (element != undefined)
        element.style.display = "block";
   }
</script>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
#paragraph {
    display: none;
}
</STYLE> 
</head>
 <body class="body" onload="execute()">
   <div align="center">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <p id="paragraph">
       <input type="text" id="example" value="Foobar" >&nbsp;<a href="#"><img border="0" src="images/some.gif"  alt="Test"></a></p>
      </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

In the onModuleLoad() i simply do this: `System.out.println(Document.get().getElementById("paragraph")
                .getAbsoluteLeft());`

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: Wow.. when i read your question i already was at home but i thought i know the DOM structure so i can build a simple test case. When i did somehow everything worked as expected. Then after several tests it hit me i'm pretty sure the reason is that the element i'm trying to fetch the absoluteLeft value has the style. display:none and is gets display:block on body load. I've made a little example which i will attach asap. What i don't know is why it works in IE (meaning returns an appropriate left value) but not in FF.

Comment: You need to be really careful in situations like this in order to not run into some nasty race conditions. The order you put your script tags and CSS (if linking to external files instead of the CSS being inline) may determine whether the JavaScript fires before the layout happens. IE is probably running onModuleLoad before your CSS display:none takes effect, giving you the original value. FF is more than likely waiting to fire onModuleLoad until after the CSS display:none hits but before the body's onload, giving you 0, which is correct when display is none.

Comment: Is it possible to execute the onModuleLoad after everything is done. My Script will injected into a page and i can not control what other scripts or css will be used. So i guess the safest way is to be the last one who gets executed. My initial thought was to put the nocache.js include at least but i don't think this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as stated in the comments the problem was that the element is not visible which results into 2 different behavoirs for IE and FF.